# AutoCompleteTextView not working in Huawei devices

Tags: android, android-fragments, autocomplete

I have an application which uses `AutoCompleteTextView` to show suggestions for Airports. My application supports Two languages - English and Arabic. I have implemented this `AutoCompleteTextView` in `dialog view` for the same. The code which I have used is as follows:

```
final AutoCompleteTextView fromactv  = (AutoCompleteTextView) fromDialog.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1d);
            final TextView no_match_tv  = (TextView) fromDialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_no_match);
            final ImageButton close     = (ImageButton) fromDialog.findViewById(R.id.ib_close);
            fromactv.setText(null);
            final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
            OnItemClickListener onitem=new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
                    String actvstringfrom = fromactv.getText().toString();

                    String resource[];
                    if(CommonFunctions.lang.equalsIgnoreCase("ar")){
                        resource     = actvstringfrom.split(" \t ");
                        actvstringfrom = resource[0];
                    }

                    strFromCity = actvstringfrom;
                    resource = actvstringfrom.split("-");
                    strFromCode = resource[3];
                    strFromCode = strFromCode.replace(" ", "");

                    tvFromCode.setText(strFromCode);
                    tvFromCity.setText(strFromCity);

                   if(resource[1].toLowerCase().contains("all airport") ||
                            resource[1].toLowerCase().contains("جميع المطار"))
                            allAirportFrom = "Y";
                        else
                            allAirportFrom = "N";

                    Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("strFromCode", strFromCode);
                    editor.putString("allAirportFrom", allAirportFrom);
                    editor.commit();

                    fromDialog.dismiss();

                }
            };
            fromactv.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                        int count) {

                    String filter = s.toString().toLowerCase();
                    listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (String listItem : arrayAirportList) {
                        if (listItem.toLowerCase().contains(filter))
                        {
                            listItems.add(listItem);
                        }

                    }
                    if (listItems.size() == 0)
                    {
                        if(no_match_tv.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                            no_match_tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(no_match_tv.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                            no_match_tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                            R.layout.tv_autocomplete, listItems);
                    fromactv.setAdapter(adapt);
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });

            fromactv.setOnItemClickListener(onitem);
            fromDialog.show();
```

This code is working fine for most of the phones except **Honor** devices. And issue is only in Arabic version. Have someone experienced such an issue? How can I handle this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Same here... with a P9 device and Hebrew language

Answer (score 0):

Finally got to the bottom of it:
for some obscure reason, HUAWEI devices fail to set the AutoComplete popup width to the parent's width when setting it to fill_parent or match_parent - and when the device is set to an RTL language such as Hebrew or Arabic.
I found a workaround (no so pretty - but is the best I got):

```
AutoCompleteTextView field = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(<YOUR_ID>);
String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
if(manufacturer.equals("HUAWEI")){
    View parent = (View)field.getParent();
    int width = parent.getWidth();
    field.setDropDownWidth(width);
}
```

This code seems to work fine on both RTL and non RTL languages.
B.T.W: you can skip the IF and it will still work for all other devices as well. I added it to emphasize that it is workaround for a specific device.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Will try this one.